# Change another process audio output device on Windows

Tags: winapi, wasapi

Ultimately I want to redirect process audio output elsewhere in real time. There's a standard way to do that via WASAPI: [`AUDIOCLIENT_PROCESS_LOOPBACK_PARAMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/applicationloopbackaudio-sample/). The problem is this approach keeps the process playing its audio to the default output device.

In order to prevent process from polluting the default output device, I want to make it output to a virtual null-output sound device instead.

How do I do that? Is there a standard way to make 3rd party process think the default audio device is not the one used by the rest of the system? If not, what is the best way to lie to the process about which device is the default one via something like [`Detours`](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours)?

Comment: The most stable/reliable way would be to create a virtual driver device  and route it whatever you want. Something of a virtual cable.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis the device is not the problem. The problem is how to send process output to it.

Comment: Does [Audio Router](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router) work for you?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT thanks, it appears to work for many scenarios.